# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\theta}{2+\sin(\theta)}$ using Cauchy's integral theorem even tho it isn't from 0 to 2pi?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

> Evaluate using Cauchy's integral theorem
> $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d\theta}{2+\sin(\theta)}.$$

I understand the idea is to use $\sin(\theta) = \frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}$ and $z = e^{i\theta}$ to convert into the  complex plane and simplified to:
$$2\oint_C{\frac{dz}{z^{2}+4zi-1}}$$
which after plugging into the quadratic equation yields the singularities
$i(\sqrt{3}-2), 
-i(\sqrt{3}+2)$

applying Cauchy's Integral Theorem

$$2\oint_C{\frac{dz}{z^{2}+4zi-1}} = 2\pi{i}\sum_{k_i}{\operatorname{Res}(f(z);k_i)}$$ where $k_i =$ all singularities.

My expectation is that $2\pi{i}\sum_{k_i}{\operatorname{Res}(f(z);k_i)} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$

If I realize that Cauchy's is applied over $\int_{0}^{2\pi}$ but my original integral was only over $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ I also put a $\frac{1}{4}$ conversion factor on the integral to change the bounds, which would yield $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$.

This is what I assumed the answer to be from what I understand about this process. However it seems the true result:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2+\sin(\theta)} = \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$

obviously $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}$ and $\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$ are different by a factor of $\frac{2}{3}$.

I then solved the problem also using the form $$\oint_C{\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}} = \frac{2\pi{i}}{n!}\cdot f^{(n)}(z_0)$$

to check my result, however this also resulted in the same thing I got the other way, i.e. the wrong answer. After testing everything I have not been able to figure out what it could be unless when converting the integrals from $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ to a contour over $\oint_C$. You can't actually just adjust the range as I did. And I should be getting a factor of $\frac16$ instead of $\frac14$. But I can't figure out why. Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you guessed it, the new domain of integration is only a quarter of the unit circle, so that your countour is not closed and you cannot use Cauchy's theorem as such.

Comment: You appear to be asking two questions: (a) how to solve this integral, (b) what is going wrong with your method. Please clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The expected symmetry does not hold for the function $\displaystyle f(\theta)=\frac{1}{2+\sin \theta}.$

---

The integral can be evaluated by computing the contour integral over the quarter circle.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{2+\sin \theta}=2\int_1^{e^{i\pi/2}} \frac{dz}{z^2+4iz-1}$$
$$\phantom{\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{2+\sin \theta}}=\frac{2}{z_1-z_2} \left(\int_1^{e^{i\pi/2}} \frac{dz}{z-z_1} - \int_1^{e^{i\pi/2}}\frac{dz}{z-z_2} \right),$$ where $z_1=i(\sqrt{3}-2)$ and $z_2 = -i(\sqrt{3}+2)$ are the poles of the integrand.
$$\displaystyle \int_0^{ \pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{2+\sin \theta}=\frac{2}{z_1-z_2}\left[ \log(z-z_1) - \log (z-z_2) \right]_1^{e^{i\pi/2}}$$
$$= \frac{1}{i\sqrt{3}}\log \left[\frac{(3-\sqrt{3})}{(3+\sqrt{3})} \frac{(1+i(\sqrt{3}+2))}{(1-i(\sqrt{3}-2))}\right]$$
$$= \frac{1}{i\sqrt{3}} \log \left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)= \frac{1}{i\sqrt{3}} \log e^{i\pi/3}$$ $$= \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.$$

$\underline{\text{Reference:}}$
Carrier, Krook, and Pearson, **Functions of a Complex Variable**, Ch. 3, pp. 86,87.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: In the $z$ integrals you forgot to change the integration limits.

Comment: @Gary, thank you.  will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{2+\sin\theta}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{2+\cos\theta}\stackrel{x=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{=}\int_0^1\frac{2dx}{x^2+3}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x^2+3}
$$
Take the counter clock-wise contour $z=-1+iy, y:\infty\to 0$ then $z=x, -1\leq x\leq1$ then $z=1+iy, 0\leq y<\infty$. By residue theorem after combining the integrals on the two vertical rays, we have
$$I+\int_0^\infty\frac{4ydy}{y^4-4y^2+16}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}$$
and now letting $y^2=2x+2$ we have
$$2I+\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+3}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}\tag1$$
Similarly,
$$2I+\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{dx}{x^2+3}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}\tag2$$
From $(1)$, $(2)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+3}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}$
we have $3I=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}$.